# How would you get more data from user upon signup with passport?

Tags: passport.js, registration

I am trying to rebuild a website from php/mysql to express, I am using passport for authentication. My question is, how would you go for getting additional data from the user apart username and password, after the signup with passport-local strategy?
I mean, if I add the data in the registration process then, as far as I can understand, I won't be able to use fb / twitter / google signup and get the same data. So I thought I should let the user register with username and password or similar and then prompt him a request to fill in more data.
I have a general idea of how this should be done but since I am new to all this I'd like to get some feedback here.